# I want to get values from object, but I unable to do. object key also start with lowercase. Used ObjectMapper convertValue and readValue

Tags: java, object, extract

This is the respose body and I need to get value from sr_number

*

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "errorCode": "00",
    "errorDescription": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "complaintResponse": {
            "issueId": "3805889",
            "sr_number": "2-0001617643"
        }
    }
}
```

- 

I used ObjectMapper convertvalue and readValue. But occured unrecognised error for `complaintResponse`.

```
Class ComplaintResponse

*import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ComplaintResponse {

    private String issueId;
    private String sr_number;
}*
```

Anyone have idea to solve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson annotation : JsonProperty, like this:

```
        @Data
        class ComplaintResponse {
            private String issueId;
            @JsonProperty("sr_number")
            private String srNumber;
            protected String getsrNumber(){return srNumber;}
        }
```